# Report frame in VF page is empty

Tags: visualforce, reporting

I have a report taking an object ID parameter to filter with. I'm trying to display that report in an iFrame in a VF page but the frame is blank.

In the browser the following URL works:

```
https://na15.salesforce.com/00Oi0000005eMOa?pv0=a08i000000FD9BC
```

In the VF Page the first thing I tried was:

```
<iFrame id="reportFrame" scrolling="no" src="/00Oi0000005eMOa?pv0=a08i000000FD9BC"></iFrame>
```

I also tried it with an absolute URL instead.

I figured it the problem might be the short form of the object IDs so I got the long forms and tried again:

```
<iFrame id="reportFrame" scrolling="yes" src="/00Oi0000005eMOaEAM?pv0=a08i000000FD9BCAA1"></iFrame>
```

The frame is always empty in the VF page and I'd appreciate any help.  The saved form of the report has an empty value for the filter parameter so that output is blank as it should be, and I'm not certain whether Im getting no output whatsoever or the blank output.  In the browser even if you get zero records you get at least the header in the results section.

As per request, here is the actual page:

```
<apex:page standardController="URLTester__c"  >
  Report Frame short form ID with parameter:
  <div id="reportDiv1" style="border:1px solid black" >
    <iFrame id="reportFrame1" style="border:1px solid black"  src="/00Oi0000005eMOa?pv0=a08i000000FD9BC"/>
    <apex:iFrame id="reportFrame2" src="/00Oi0000005eMOa?pv0=a08i000000FD9BC"/>
  </div>
  Report Frame long form ID with parameter:
  <div id="reportDiv2" style="border:1px solid black" >
    <iFrame id="reportFrame2"  style="border:1px solid black"  src="/00Oi0000005eMOaEAM?pv0=a08i000000FD9BCAA1"/> 
    <apex:iFrame id="reportFrame4" src="/00Oi0000005eMOaEAM?pv0=a08i000000FD9BCAA1"/>
  </div>
  Second report no param short form ID:
  <div id="reportDiv3" style="border:1px solid black" >
    <iFrame id="reportFrame5" style="border:1px solid black"  src="/00Oi0000005eMOQ"/>
    <apex:iFrame id="reportFrame6" src="/00Oi0000005eMOQ"/>
  </div>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: can you paste your VF page sometimes IFrames can be tricky if used within some apex tags. Also check out it your issue is related to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279898/why-iframe-control-is-not-loading-the-source-page-in-visual-force-preview

Comment: Reading the link you provided, I'm getting the following in the JavaScript console: <br/> Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://login.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2F00Oi0000005eMOaEAM%3Fpv0%3Da08i000000FD9BCAA1 does not permit framing.

Comment: Looks like a browser issue. The web content setting should be adjusted on Chrome(assuming you are using chrome). Did you try to load the same page using IE or mozilla / another computer? Use this article to adjust the content setting https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/114662 if you are using chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if block Block third-party cookies and site data is checked for chrome if it checked uncheck the option.

Click on Settings --> navigate to the bottom ( show advanced settings ) --> under privacy click on content settings.

[image]

Comment: It was Firefox, not Chrome, but the concept was the same. I changed the third party cookies from Never to From Visited and it worked.  IE on the settings I already had worked as well.

Comment: @eric can you mark this answer solved for the benefit of people who come here later with the same query.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that as of Spring '14, no Salesforce page (which includes report pages) can be used in an iframe because of ClickJack protection.